# search sub form from text box in form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form (frm_main)

and i have a subform on this form (frm_weblogs_subform)

I am trying to search the subform using a text box.

the code i've found and have been playing with to no avail is:

```
Private Sub find_weblog_button_Click()

Dim D As Database
Dim wlog As DAO.Recordset
Dim Criteria As String

Set D = CurrentDb
Set wlog = D.OpenRecordset("form_frm_weblogs_subform", dbOpenDynaset)

Criteria = "[weblog_number]='" & [weblogSearch] & "'"

wlog.FindFirst Criteria

wlog.Close

End Sub
```

It doesn't seem to register the form at all it keeps saying it can't be found.

can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should read:

```
Dim wlog As DAO.Recordset
Dim Criteria As String

Set wlog = Me!<NameOfTheSubformCONTROL>.RecordsetClone
If wlog.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Criteria = "[weblog_number]='" & [weblogSearch] & "'"
    wlog.FindFirst Criteria
    If wlog.NoMatch = False
        ' Found.
    Else
        ' Not found.
    End If
End If
wlog.Close
```

Replace `<NameOfTheSubformCONTROL>` with that, not the name of the subform.